# Weechat and Gitter

Tags: weechat

I am using Weechat. I know that Gitter has a IRC and from Weechat I am planning to connect to it. There are plenty of guides for Irssi, not for Weechat. However, I have tried to use similar commands to Irssi and I am getting errors.

How could I use Weechat with Gitter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By following the following [IRC Gitter guide](https://gist.github.com/raine/2700329b9a397b8c0228):

> /server add gitter irc.gitter.im -ssl -ssl_verify -ssl_dhkey_size=1024 -password=
>   /connect gitter

You get your token in this website. You log in and copy-paste the token with the password above. However, please note that it is very important to specify the nick as well. Otherwise, you could connect to Gitter but the service will throw the following error:

> irc: reading data on socket: error 0 (connection closed by peer)

In order to avoid this problem, specify the nick:

> /set irc.server.gitter.nicks "YOUR_NICK"

Answer (score 0):

I'v successfully joined Gitter via Weechat but none of my channels show up in the sidebar and when I try to join one (i.e. `/join #neoclide/coc.nvim` nothing happens.